Listening for changes in the `inccommand=split` preview buffers
I'm attempting to write a small lua script that can track the changes in the inccommand=split preview window. In essence, I want to have some kind of programmatic notification when the preview list changes, and be able to retrieve those updated previews.
An iteration of this script used the CmdlineChanged autocmd to watch as I typed my substitution command, and would fetch the preview buffer contents as I typed. However, it seems this event was fired before the preview buffer updated, which necessitated me doing something to the effect of
api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "CmdlineChanged" }, {
  callback = function()
    vim.defer_fn(fetch_preview, 250)
  end,
})

This works, but it would be nice if I were able to fetch these updates in a bit more "real time". I hoped I could use nvim_buf_attach to listen for the buffer changes directly, but it seems that on_lines is never fired for this preview window, even with the preview flag marked true (which the docs for nvim_buf_attach seem to suggest are for this purpose). I have also tried binding to the current buffer, rather than the preview buffer, but alas, the preview events do not come through.
A MWE follows. You can open this file in nvim and run :source %, :set icm=split, and then type :%s/<some chars> to force the preview pane to show. :messages will be empty. Is there something I'm missing here (perhaps something special about the preview buffer that prevents the on_line callback from working?)
local api, fn = vim.api, vim.fn

local function find_preview_buf()
  local preview_buf
  local bufs = api.nvim_list_bufs()
  for _, buf in ipairs(bufs) do
    if
      vim.bo[buf].buftype == "nofile"
      and fn.bufname(buf) == "[Preview]"
    then
      preview_buf = buf
      break
    end
  end

  return preview_buf
end

local split_listener_registered = false
local function listen_for_split_completion()
  if split_listener_registered then
    return
  end

  local preview_buf = find_preview_buf()
  if not preview_buf then
    return
  end

  attached = api.nvim_buf_attach(preview_buf, false, {
    on_lines = function(_, buf, changedtick, firstline, lastline, new_lastline, bytecount)
      print(string.format("Buffer %d changed: %d-%d to %d", buf, firstline, lastline, new_lastline))
    end,
    preview = true,
  })
  split_listener_registered = true
end

api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "CmdlineEnter" }, {
  callback = function()
    split_listener_registered = false
  end,
})

api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "CmdlineChanged" }, {
  callback = listen_for_split_completion,
})

